# expose service interface to multiple entities or repositories

Tags: spring-roo

I've ran the below ROO command to expose a service interface to an entity class, one to one mapping.

```
service --entity ~.model.Course --interface ~.service.CourseService
```

Question:
I would like one service interface to be exposed to multiple entities (or jpa's)
e.g CourseService exposed to entities model.Course and model.Student

1. What should the ROO command look like for multiple entities?
2. Also, what ROO command can I run to expose the above service to repository classes (jpa's) and not enity classes?

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge this is not possible through command line however following approach works.

Consider you want to create a single Service with ~.model.Course and ~.model.Student

1. Create the Service associated with single domain entity using command line.

   `service --entity ~.model.Course --interface ~.service.CourseService`
2. Open the CourseService interface and add the Student.class in the @RooService annotation. The code should be

   ```
   @RooService(domainTypes = { Course.class, Student.class })

   public interface CourseService {

     ..........

     ..........

   }
   ```

Spring roo will automatically add the required method related to Student class into the CourseService itself.